# Excel Sheet copy from gridview in formated excel file

Tags: c#, excel

i have a design excel sheet i wants to copy each of rows from grid view to excel existing sheet. In grid view i have same columns  that i have columns in my design excel. I don't wants to exports into excel i wants to copy my data into existing excel sheet if there is a way so please share it.

Comment: What have you searched so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) Excel library. The below code get data from gridview and copy to an existing sheet:

```
// Load the existing Excel file
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument();
workbook.easy_LoadXLSFile(pathToExistingExcel);

// Get the first sheet
ExcelWorksheet sheet = (ExcelWorksheet)workbook.easy_getSheetAt(0);

// Create a dataset that keeps the gridview datatable
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add((DataTable)gridView.DataSource);

// Insert gridview data into sheet
sheet.easy_insertDataSet(dataset, false);

// Choose a name for the xls file 
string fileName = "Excel.xls";
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

// Export new Excel file and prompt the "Open or Save Dialog Box"
workbook.easy_WriteXLSFile(Response.OutputStream);
```

If you have to format the data and for more details check this link about [how to export GridView to Excel using EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-gridview-to-excel.html).

Comment: How to export specific grid view columns to formatted excel? for example If the grid view contains 6 columns but in my formatted excel I have only 3 columns?

Comment: If you don't want to alter the gridview source, the easiest solution is to create a copy of the DataTable (DataTable.Copy method) and remove the extra columns (DataTable.Columns.Remove method). Or you can populate the Excel file, cell by cell with data from the GridView: http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/import-export-excel-data.html

Comment: Thanks friend, I will check and get back to you if I have any concern